# Internet Explorer not parsing javascript method

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've got a webpage with filtering. The filtering uses a javascript file which is linked in the header like such:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.werkenbijtauw.nl/static/default/script/autotag.js"></script>`

The contents of the file define a autotag method:

```
var autotag = {
filter: function(container, resetPage = true){
    if(resetPage)
        $('#filter-page').val('1')

    var form    = $('#'+container);
    var action  = form.attr('action');
    var method  = form.attr('method');
    var data    = form.serialize()+'&method=ajax';

    $.ajax({
      url: action,
      data: data,
      method:method,
      success: function(response, status, xhr){
        history.pushState(null,null, window.location.pathname+'?'+form.serialize());
        $('#'+container).html(response);
      }
    });
 }
};
```

In the body of my html I've got the following html:

`<input type="checkbox" id="Bodem" name="filters['function'][]" value="Bodem" onchange="autotag.filter('vacancies-filters');" />`

In Chrome and Firefox this doesn't result in any problems. On the other hand IE throws an autotag is not defined error. Any ideas why IE would consider the autotag variable undefined?

Comment: Place the script tag at the bottom of your document...just before the closing </body> tag.... or add a defer attribute to the scripts in the head that need to wait until the DOM parsing is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="https://www.werkenbijtauw.nl/static/default/script/autotag.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this didn't resolve my problem it helped me find the problem. Internet Explorer wasn't properly parsing a function where a default value was set. So ```function(someValue, someBoolean = true){ if(someBoolean){}}``` is something IE 11 didn't parse too well. So I ended up changing the method to ```function(someValue, someBoolean){if(someValue == null || someValue)} ```

Comment: another tip: set up IE to record developer console messages... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"... Save changes..... To debug errors that occur during page load... f12>Debug tab, select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown (looks like a stop sign)... pin the dev tool to IE... !important the dev tool must be opened when you are debugging. Press ctrl+f5 to hard-refresh the page you are debugging... the dev tool will now break when errors are encountered... normally (when the dev tool is not open) scripting exceptions are just ignored.